# How to get chat history of Teams bot using ConversationState?

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

I am using Teams Toolkit to integrate Teams bot with backend LLM application for which I need the previous chat (questions asked by user and replies of bot) to feed into prompt generator.

I've created "bot sso" using sample app by teams toolkit and MemoryStorage is being used to save current chat conversation:
[image]

[image]

Tried following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) but this did not work.

I'm probably not able to use to Load method correctly. Can someone please help here on how to implement this?

Comment: Are you attempting to deploy to multiple instances? If so, memory storage will not work. You'll need to use cloud storage.

Comment: @AP01, single instance of backend application is running

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code where you load the state?